# Visual Studio 2012 Debug not working after windows 7 update?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have VS 2012 and working fine for long time. Today Windows 7 automatically updated and IE upgrade to 10.

Then I try to debug my solution with VS2012, it wont't stop at any break point set in code!

how to resolve this issue?

More info:
1. When I hit debug in VS 2012 IDE at first time, the SL app can not be accessed in browser, I got error message in browser:This page can't be displayed. Because built-in web server of VS 2012 not start it. I need to hit debug button again. 
2. When the app finally accessible in browser, break point can't be captured. Move cursor to break point as Peter suggested, got following message:

The break point will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

I search over internet with the info and try to figure out setting for symbol, and it's not working.

Also try Phil's advice, change IE 10 Security setting to Low.  Not working.

Not sure why.

Comment: Are the breakpoints binding? If not, what's it say when you hover your cursor over them?  Did the module's symbolic information (.pdb) load?

Comment: Have you tried manually attaching to the process?

Comment: Yes, manually attaching process working. Crazy! What Windows update doing? and how to put it back as default same as before?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when I updated IE on my development server. It sounds like a security issue in IE. Check your browser security and disable it as needed.